# Workboxjs precacheAndRoute not serving new content

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have created an offline documentation with [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) and [Workboxjs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/).

I execute `workbox generateSW` on the files generated by MkDocs which generates a Service Worker with precache setup with the precacheAndRoute function.

This works fine but when I update the documentation and generate new html files and the Service Worker it does not serve the new content until I completely close the browser. Refreshing or just closing the tab is not enough.

The worker is updating the content to the Cache Storage correctly which I can see from the Chrome devtools (Application -> Cache Storage -> workbox-precache*) but no matter how many times I hit refresh the browser won't display the new content.

I use this function to register the Service Worker

```
async function register() {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(SW_URL);

    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;

        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
            if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                    console.log(
                        "New content is available; please refresh."
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log("Content is cached for offline use.");
                }
            }
        };
    };
}
```

I wonder if I have to do something extra to make the content refresh properly?

My workbox-config.js is

```
module.exports = {
    globDirectory: ".doc_build",
    globPatterns: ["**/*"],
    swDest: ".doc_build/sw.js"
};
```

This happens on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: chrome dev-tools in the 'application' tab u can 'force' a reload of the new SW.. try that approach and refresh may work

Comment: @RobertRowntree Of course I can force the refresh from the devtools. The issue is with my users who cannot do that but need the new content asap.

Comment: https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Robert Rowntree's link in the question comment I figured this out.

I my case the content gets refreshed to cache the but old version of the precache service worker still keeps running which has a list of objects like this

```
{
  "url": "index.html",
  "revision": "e4919b0cd0e772b3beb2d1f3d09af437"
}
```

as you can see it has the checksum of the old version in it and it will keep serving that until the old service worker gets deactivated and the new one activated.

It is possible to see that by checking `registration.waiting` when the old service worker is waiting for to be deactivated and new one to be installed. It seems that browser does this "at some point". It actually seems to happen if I just keep the tabs closed long enough.

The solution for my question is to force the service worker to skip the waiting period. It is possible to do that by sending a message to the service worker from the update event

```
async function register() {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(SW_URL);
    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = async () => {
            if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                    console.log(
                        "New content is available; please refresh."
                    );
                    // Send message to the service worker telling
                    // it should stop waiting for browser to deactivate it
                    registration.waiting.postMessage("skipWaiting");
                } else {
                    console.log("Content is cached for offline use.");
                }
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Then in the Service Worker code I had to handle that message and call `skipWaiting()`

```
self.addEventListener("message", messageEvent => {
    if (messageEvent.data === "skipWaiting") {
        return skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

To do this I had to move from `workbox generateSW` to `workbox injectManifest` to be able to add the skipping code.

But there are caveats in this solution. Read from the Robert's link onwards from

> "The simplest and most dangerous approach is to just skip waiting during installation."

https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

Fortunately this is good enough for my case.